# Unable to start the rails app with puma-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, puma-dev

Unable to start the rails app using puma-dev.

`rails -v`
Rails 5.2.3

`ruby -v`
ruby 2.4.9p362 (2019-10-02 revision 67824) [x86_64-linux]

Getting this error:

```rb
TestApp[30168]: /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/lib/nio4r_ext.so (LoadError)
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/lib/nio.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/reactor.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/launcher.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
TestApp[30168]:     from /home/lt-238/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/puma-4.3.1/bin/puma:6:in `<top (required)>'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/bin/puma:23:in `load'
TestApp[30168]:     from /usr/local/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
! Killing 'TestApp' (30168)
* App 'TestApp' shutdown and cleaned up
! Detecting app 'TestApp' dying on start
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try `gem pristine --all` in the project directory

Comment: Tried the same but not luck.. same error

Comment: @ShekharPatil Os Mac OSX ?

Comment: Did you try deleting the gem and running `bundle install` again?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and tried deleting the gem and ```bundle i``` but no luck